# SQL Server 2005 I would like to able to select a function which i declared as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server which contains the names of certain functions.

Is it possible to select a function based on a string stored in a table?

Normally I would execute the below in SSMS

```
SELECT dbo.udfGetFileName ()
```

But instead I want to be able to get the same result by getting the name of the function out of a table

```
DECLARE @GetFileName VARCHAR(30); 
SET @GetFileName = (SELECT FunctionName FROM Functions)
SELECT @GetFileName ()
```

Something like the above, obviously variables won't work but I was wondering if I could get some ideas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write it as dynamic SQL.

```
declare @GetFileName varchar(30);
declare @query  nvarchar(1024)

select @GetFileName  = functionName from Functions
set @query = 'select ' +  @GetFileName
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build up the sql as a string and then execute it using `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @GetFileName VARCHAR(30); 
SET @GetFileName = (SELECT FunctionName FROM Functions)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'select ' + @GetFileName

exec sp_executesql @sql
```